# Google Chart - Legend Titles are not ordered

Tags: google-visualization

Here is the URL for Google Chart:

http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=550x325&chds=0,162&chxt=y&chts=000000,15&cht=bhs&chd=t:-1,-1,-1,1,-1|5,1,2,3,3|10,12,10,11,14|58,48,47,40,48|89,101,103,107,97|-1,-1,-1,-1,-1&chco=A91E2A,E95251,E41D38,E24733,E28B50,EEC41A,EFD050,5C573D,686450,A7AF5D|A91E2A,E95251,E41D38,E24733,E28B50,EEC41A,EFD050,5C573D,686450,A7AF5D|A91E2A,E95251,E41D38,E24733,E28B50,EEC41A,EFD050,5C573D,686450,A7AF5D|A91E2A,E95251,E41D38,E24733,E28B50,EEC41A,EFD050,5C573D,686450,A7AF5D|A91E2A,E95251,E41D38,E24733,E28B50,EEC41A,EFD050,5C573D,686450,A7AF5D|A91E2A,E95251,E41D38,E24733,E28B50,EEC41A,EFD050,5C573D,686450,A7AF5D&chm=N,000000,0,,12,,c|N,000000,1,,12,,c|N,000000,2,,12,,c|N,000000,3,,12,,c|N,000000,4,,12,,c|N,000000,5,,12,,c&chxl=0:|AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD|EEE&chdl=Very+Poor|Somewhat+Poor|Neutral|Somewhat+Good+|Very+Good|Nothing&chdlp=b&chxs=0,000000,15|1,000000,15&chdls=000000,15&chbh=40,15,15

You can see I am using legend like:

chdl=Very+Poor|Somewhat+Poor|Neutral|Somewhat+Good+|Very+Good|Nothing

But this is not displaying in the order I am writing.

Anyone can help me, Please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the order of the legend entries with [the `chdlp` parameter](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html#gcharts_legend). Use `<opt_label_order>` of `l` to display labels in the order given to `chdl`.

http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=550x325&chds=0,162&chxt=y&chts=000000,15&cht=bhs&chd=t:-1,-1,-1,1,-1|5,1,2,3,3|10,12,10,11,14|58,48,47,40,48|89,101,103,107,97|-1,-1,-1,-1,-1&chco=A91E2A,E95251,E41D38,E24733,E28B50,EEC41A,EFD050,5C573D,686450,A7AF5D|A91E2A,E95251,E41D38,E24733,E28B50,EEC41A,EFD050,5C573D,686450,A7AF5D|A91E2A,E95251,E41D38,E24733,E28B50,EEC41A,EFD050,5C573D,686450,A7AF5D|A91E2A,E95251,E41D38,E24733,E28B50,EEC41A,EFD050,5C573D,686450,A7AF5D|A91E2A,E95251,E41D38,E24733,E28B50,EEC41A,EFD050,5C573D,686450,A7AF5D|A91E2A,E95251,E41D38,E24733,E28B50,EEC41A,EFD050,5C573D,686450,A7AF5D&chm=N,000000,0,,12,,c|N,000000,1,,12,,c|N,000000,2,,12,,c|N,000000,3,,12,,c|N,000000,4,,12,,c|N,000000,5,,12,,c&chxl=0:|AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD|EEE&chdl=Very+Poor|Somewhat+Poor|Neutral|Somewhat+Good+|Very+Good|Nothing&chdlp=b|l&chxs=0,000000,15|1,000000,15&chdls=000000,15&chbh=40,15,15